# The python pandas to_csv function is missing rows when outputting to AWS s3 bucket on Heroku

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku

The script is running fine but I get 2 different outputs converting dataframe to csv when ran on Anaconda Jupyter notebook on windows vs on Heroku.

The issue seems to be related to index but cannot figure it out. The csv index column from Heroku jumps from 10 to 433 (see below). The version generated by Jupyter is displaying correctly at first glance.

***code I am using to send write dataframe to csv and send to s3 bucket:***

```
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False, key=config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,   secret=config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY )
with s3.open('test-bucket/playoffgamelogs.csv','w') as f:
    df_gamelogs.to_csv(f, line_terminator='\n')
```

***csv generated from desktop:***
[image]

***csv generated from Heroku:***
[image]